# nginx location only for specific subdomain?

Tags: nginx

I inherited an nginx config that is a few hundred separate subdomain configs, all of which just do a proxy_pass and replace the a specific ID in proxy_pass like this:

```
server {
  server_name somedomain.example.com;
  [snip]
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/1234;
  }
}
```

Obvious solution: switch to a mapping and change the code like so, eliminating all the repeated configs:

```
map $host $proj_id{
  somedomain.example.com 1234;
  otherdomain.example.com 2345;
}

server {
  server_name *.example.com;
  [snip]
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/$proj_id;
  }
}
```

During this process I found that some subdomains have hacked-in short-url redirects like so:

```
location = /someshorturl {
 return 301 https://asdf.example.com/[some-long-path-and-query];
}
```

These short-urls are not unique to a specific subdomain, so I cannot just have them as a general rule in the catchall config. Short of keeping these domain configs entirely separate is there some way to actually say "if domain = [that specific subdomain] and location = / ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an answer over on Reddit ... and it quite simply is to use more maps:

```
map $host$uri $mapped_redirect {
  default 0;
  domain123.example.com/someshorturl https://domain.123.example.com/whatever;
}

server {
  if ($mapped_redirect) { return 301 $mapped_redirect; }
}
```

Which is neat because it allows for all redirects to be defined in one central place, instead of being a ton of separate location rules.